# How to code this in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have three models and their corresponding tables and controllers:

- Request
- DirectPatch
- UTPFiberPatch

The user creates a new request and defines the type of request: Direct or UTP/Fiber

Once the user hits save, the Request will be saved and the user will be redirected to an edit screen to create all the patch entries corresponding to that request.

- Each patch entry will be saved as a single row in either the Direct or UTP table depending on the type of request selected. A column called request_id will act as the foreign key.
- The view and form will be different for both Direct and UTP/Fiber.
- The user can view all requests on a single homepage and click to edit. The user can then see all the patch rows for that request on a single page and click to edit existing or add new.

  1. What would be the best way to set up the routing, controllers and
     views for this?
  2. How does the Request ID get passed when creating new patches and automatically saved?

I'm not sure exactly what the technical name is for the problem I'm having if there is one, but I'm happy to add more detail and answer questions if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a polymorphic association on the request model:

```
belongs_to :patch, :polymorphic => true
```

Add to your Request table two columns:

```
patch_id : integer
patch_type : string
```

When you create a request and the user selects the patch type, you assign this patch object to your request, which will populate the two new columns.  From you request model you can then call

```
request.patch
```

Which will give you back the appropriate type of patch based on the details stored in the database (note - you can't do eager loading with polymorphic associations).

To do the views you can render a partial in the edit screen, based upon which type of patch it is.

Comment: Thanks, I've just been reading more about polymorphic associations and wondered if that's really the best way to do it? From a logical point of view, a Request has many DirectPatches or UTPFiberPatches, depending on the type of request selected. But are you saying association is the other way round, the request belongs to the patch?